# Meteor collection find() method is undefined even though its subscribed

Tags: javascript, meteor, meteor-collections

I'm trying to implement a photo viewer app that stores image url and it's belonging user id in a collection. When I try to Collection.findOne that value it always returns null.

```
var name = Meteor.user().username;
var message = $('.action-textarea').val();
var userId = Meteor.userId();
var file = $("#input-photo").get(0).files[0];
if(file) {
    fsFile = new FS.File(file);
    var id = PostGeneralImages.insert(fsFile, function(err, result) { 
        if(err) {
            throw new Meteor.Error(err);
        } else { 
            var imageLoc = '/cfs/files/PostImages/' + result._id;
            PostImages.insert({
                    generalId: result._id,
                    userId: Meteor.userId(),
                    username: Meteor.user().username,
                    imageLoc: imageLoc
                });       
            }
        });
    }
var imagePath = PostImages.findOne({generalId: id._id}).imageLoc;
console.log(imagePath);
```

imagePath is undefined on console. But when I try findOne method in console it successfully returns the wanted object. I'm already publishing and subscribing that collection.

Comment: You're trying to find the record before it's inserted within the callback function of the `PostGeneralImages.insert` function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solution for your problem:

get the result in the **callback** of the insert function cause insert works asynchronously.

Comment: yes fetching is working. The problem is that when I fetch from code it returns an empty array. But if I try browser console, it returns the image object array. I don't understand what I am doing wrong

Comment: have you tried to get the result in the callback of the insert function?